# dir() and list.files() fail to list file names with East Asian characters after R update

Tags: r

`dir()` and `list.files()` list all files names in R version 4.2.3, but not in R version 4.3.2.

#### R version 4.2.3

[image: version 4.2.3]

#### R version 4.3.2

[image: version 4.3.2]

Comment: both images show the files, whats your question?

Comment: @Onyambu, the outputs differ in both images. If OP assures us that both those paths are exactly the same (since most of us cannot read such Asian characters), then this would be curious. However, files look to be Jupiter notebooks (.ipynb) which can be temporary files depending on sessions. We need to know more of your environment. Please test `dir` on a directory with stable files.

Comment: But  all files could be displayed in version 4.2.3

Comment: Version 4.3.2  dir() could display all files in some paths,  couldn't in other paths. But  version 4.2.3 could display all files in any path.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you observe is related to a change in the Windows implementation of `list.files` between R versions 4.2.3 and 4.3.0.  The issue was reported on one of the mailing lists in August ([here](https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-devel/2023-August/082797.html)).  That discussion led to a patch in R-devel (revision 84960), but it is not clear whether the patch solved the issue, because the person who reported the issue did not reply.

It would be great if you could download and install R-devel ([here](https://cran.r-project.org/bin/windows/base/rdevel.html)) and verify whether `list.files` behaves correctly there.  If you do so, then please report your findings here or (ideally) [on the mailing list](https://stat.ethz.ch/mailman/listinfo/r-devel).

Comment: all files displayed when in R-devel (revision 84960)!  Thanks

Comment: @user3394975 Thanks.  The patch has just been ported from R-devel to R-patched, meaning that you will see it in the R 4.3.3 release a few months from now.